# How to pass a function from Parent to an element within a route in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to pass a function to a component through a Route , I can do it with direct children but when it comes to Routes i can't figure it how to do it.

look at the code below , i want to pass "updateUserState" function to Profile Component , the function works properly in Header component but it's not working in Profile component which lives inside the Routes .

```
class App extends React.Component {  

  updateUserState = (currentUser) => {
    if(currentUser != null) {
      this.setState({
        currentUser: currentUser
      })
    } else {
      this.setState({
        currentUser: null
      });
    }
    return this.state.currentUser;
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Header updateUserState={this.updateUserState} />
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/profile' element={<ProfilePage updateUserState={this.updateUserState} />}/>
        </Routes>
      </div>  
    );
  }
}
```

this is the code in Profile component which is completely similar to Header Component :

```
const ProfileCard = ({updateUserState}) => {  
   const signout = () => {
      handleLogout()
      updateUserState()
   }
   return (
      <div className='profile-card'>
         <a onClick={() => signout()}>
            Sign Out 
         </a>  
      </div>
   )
}
```

Update :
solved thanks to ***Abir Taheer*** !

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      currentUser: null
    }  

    this.updateUserState = this.updateUserState.bind(this);
  }


  updateUserState = (currentUser) => {
    if(currentUser != null) {
      this.setState({
        currentUser: currentUser
      }, () => console.log(this.state.currentUser))
    } else {
      this.setState({
        currentUser: null
      }, () => console.log(this.state.currentUser));
    }
    return this.state.currentUser;
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
  
        <Header currentUser={this.state.currentUser} updateUserState={this.updateUserState} />
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/profile' element={<ProfilePage updateUserState={this.updateUserState}
          currentUser={this.state.currentUser} />}
          />
        </Routes>

        
      </div>  
    );
  }
}
```

then inside ProfilePage :

```
const ProfilePage = ( {currentUser, updateUserState} ) => {
   return (
      <div>{
            currentUser ? 
            <div>
               <ProfileCard id={currentUser.id} updateUserState={updateUserState} />
            </div>
            :
            <h1>No User Signed In</h1>
      }</div>
   )
}
```

And ProfileCard :

```
const ProfileCard = ({id, updateUserState}) => {
   
   const signout = () => {
      handleLogout()
      updateUserState();
   }

   return (
      <div className='profile-card'>
         <a onClick={() => signout()}>
            Sign Out 
         </a>  
      </div>
   )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue arises because of the `this` keyword. When you're passing a function to another component you need to bind the `this` keyword to the parent instance otherwise it may not work properly.

This behavior is described in the React Docs here: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html

and more specifically further down in the page here: [Why is binding necessary at all?](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#why-is-binding-necessary-at-all)

When you bind `this` to the parent instance then it refers to the correct state and the function should work.

You need to update your component like such:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // Make sure to initialize your state accordingly
    this.state = {
      currentUser: null,
    };

    // --- This is the line you need ---
    this.updateUserState = this.updateUserState.bind(this);
  }

  updateUserState(currentUser) {
    if (currentUser != null) {
      this.setState({
        currentUser: currentUser,
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        currentUser: null,
      });
    }
    return this.state.currentUser;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Header updateUserState={this.updateUserState} />
        <Routes>
          <Route
            path="/profile"
            element={<ProfilePage updateUserState={this.updateUserState} />}
          />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you tell me how should i call that function inside the ProfilePage component ?

Comment: it's a class component not a functional

Answer (score 0):

The way you do it seems like you are rendering the component instead of passing a reference.

How I would suggest is to wrap the component in another function and return with your function passed in as a prop. So basically making another react component with the method passed in. Use that wrapper component instead:

```
const wrappedProfilePage = () => <ProfilePage updateUserState={this.updateUserState} />;

..
.
.

 <Route path='/profile' element={wrappedProfilePage}/>
```

Comment: This answer is not correct for the latest version of React router which expects an instance of an element for the `element` prop instead of just the function itself.

Comment: where should i define this Page Wrapper ?  inside the class ? in Render or in Return function ?

Comment: @tushar-shahi see here: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/components/route